# Interpret in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm a little new to freemarker (I'm a PHP guy really!)

I'm trying to evaluate a variable value as Freemarker, for example:

variable offers contains:

```
<#list blahs as blah> <#if blah> <p>${blah.foo}</p> </#if> </#list>
```

And then evaluate the above variable in Freemarker, so like below:

```
<#assign textWithFreemarker = r"${offers}"/>
<#assign evaluatedFreemarker = textWithFreemarker?interpret />  

            <h1>${evaluatedFreemarker}</h1>
```

It gives me a template error:

```
content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a transform.
```

Do I have to convert the type first?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to interpret `offers` as FTL to generate output inside that `h1` element, you just need to write:

```
<h1><@offers?interpret /></h1>
```